# Is an algebra of sets $\mathscr{A}$ "dense" in $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X,\sigma(\mathscr{A}),\mu)$ is a measure space, given any $S\in\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ is there a sequence of sets $\{A_n\}\subset\mathscr{A}$ converging to $S$ so that the associated measure $\mu$ gives $\mu(A_n)\to\mu(S)$?

**EDIT**: So consider the following attempt at this and tell me if I'm getting something wrong.

If I have a measure space $(X,\sigma(\mathscr{A}),\mu)$ derived from an associated premeasure $\mu_0$ on $\mathscr{A}$, I can define the outer measure like this:
$$\mu^*(S)=\inf\left\lbrace\sum_k\mu_0(A_k):\{A_k\}\subset\mathscr{A}, S\subset\bigcup_kA_k\right\rbrace\text{ for all } S\subset X $$
Then for all $\epsilon >0$, there is some countable collection of sets in $\mathscr{A}$ covering $S$ so that
$$\mu^*(S)\le \sum_k \mu_0(A_k) < \mu^*(S)+\epsilon \tag{1}$$
Now if $S\in\sigma(\mathscr{A})$, then the $A_k$'s and $S$ are all measurable, and $\mu^*(S)=\mu(S)$ and $\mu_0(A_k)=\mu(A_k)$ reduce (1) to

$$\mu(S)\le \sum_k \mu(A_k) < \mu(S)+\epsilon \tag{2}$$

Further, we can rewrite the union over the $A_k$'s as a union of disjoint sets in $\mathscr{A}$, $B_n=A_n\backslash \bigcup_1^{n-1}A_k\in\mathscr{A}$. So we can assume they are disjoint to begin with. Then by properties of measures, (2) becomes

$$\mu(S)\le \mu\left(\bigcup_kA_k\right) =\mu(E) < \mu(S)+\epsilon \tag{3}$$
where $E=\bigcup_kA_k$. Similarly, we can let $\bigcup_1^NA_k=E_N$.

Perhaps my original question only holds true for sets $S\in\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ of finite measure, because if $\mu(S)$ is finite, we have $\mu(E)$ finite, and we can find $N$ large so that

$$\mu(E)-\epsilon < \mu(E_N) < \mu(E) \tag{4}$$

Combining (3) and (4) we have

$$\mu(S)-\epsilon < \mu(E_N) < \mu(S) + \epsilon$$

Now this sequence $\{E_N\}$ doesn't quite converge to $S$, but if we get two indices going, say going back to (1) where we let $\epsilon=2^{-j}$ and get a collection $\{A_{jk}\}$, we end up with some sequence of sets $\{E_j\}$ at the end whose measures converge to $\mu(S)$ as $j\to \infty$? Again this isn't really showing that the ``set limit" of the $E_j$'s is well-defined or that it even exists, but I think it might, and the $E_j$'s are probably converging to some set $E$ so that $\mu(S\triangle E)=0$. I can't prove that rigorously, but it seems to be where this line of thinking is going.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: In what sense do you mean that the sequence $A_n$ converges to $S$? Is it $\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n = S$ or something else?

Comment: @Bungo I suppose I mean the conventional way - either $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$, $\cup_n^NA_n \to S$ or its counterpart.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not true, as the bottom-up approach with $\sigma$-algebra or monotone class does not work.